# using a variable in json accessing parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

my this code is working absolutely fine but what i want to do is use a variable to access json file. that is i want to use variable called buttonClicked on the place

response.result.login.happy.en.length <<(instead of .login use variable buttonclicked to access json data). is that possible ?

```
function get_message(params) {

    var messages = [];
    var buttonClicked=params.mood;



    $.ajax({
        url: 'messages.json',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function(key, val) {
                // Do processing here
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<response.result.login.happy.en.length; i++){ // here
                    messages.push(response.result.login.happy.en[i]);

                }

            });
        }
    });

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);
    return messages[index];
}
```

Comment: sure use `response.result[buttonclicked].happy.en.length`

Comment: thankx worked.. superb